# Can not resolve xwpf

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm trying to use `POI` to convert word files to the txt files , but when i use `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument` it tells me that "cannot resolve xwpf"

my `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>convert</groupId>
<artifactId>convertor</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

When I run `clean & package` it gives me `success`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you done `mvn eclipse:eclipse` ? (If of course you use eclipse)

Comment: i am using `intelliJ`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), for `XWPF` you need the `poi-ooxml` maven artifact as a dependency

Your pom will therefore want to look something like this:

```
<properties>
    <poi.version>3.10-FINAL</poi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```